# How to Convert HashSet of Integers to Comma Separated String in Java

Tags: java, hashset

I want to convert a HashSet of Integer to Comma Separated String,

so I can use the same in where clause of a MySQL query.

```
//[MySQL - Sample table Schema]
my_table
state_id INTEGER
shop_id INTEGER
```

```
Set<Integer> uniqueShopIds = shopService.GetShopIds(); // This returns HashSet<Integer>
String inClause = ; // **How do i convert the uniqueShopIds to comma separated String**
String selectQuery = String.format("SELECT DISTINCT(state_id) FROM my_table WHERE shop_id IN (%s);", inClause);
```

If there's any other way, I can use the HashSet directly in IN CLAUSE of the PreparedStatment, please share.

Comment: @azro thanks, but i want to convert set of integers to comma separated string, for set of strings, i had worked it out already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
String str = s.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(str); // prints 1,2,3
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark Bramnik

Answer (score 0):

Then there is this.

```
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

The default `toString` for a collection is a csv surrounded by `[]`

So skip the first one and remove the last one

```
String str = s.toString().substring(1).replace("]","");
```

Or just take the substring in between

```
String str = s.toString();
str = str.substring(1,str.length()-1);

System.out.println(str);
```

Both would result in

```
1, 2, 3
```